# In Gwt Drag and Drop, how to drop a widget into a right position of a VerticalPanel that already has many labels on it?

Tags: gwt, label, drag-and-drop

Ok, let say, you got a label, you got a `VerticalPanel` that has many labels on it. See this code:

```
// Make the widget draggable.
Label w = new Label("OutSide Label");
w.getElement().setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_TRUE);

// Add a DragStartHandler.
w.addDragStartHandler(new DragStartHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
    // Required: set data for the event.
    event.setData("text", "Hello World");
    // Optional: show a copy of the widget under cursor.
    event.getDataTransfer().setDragImage(w.getElement(), 10, 10);
  }
});

VerticalPanel vp=nw VerticalPanel();
vp.add(new Label("l1");
vp.add(new Label("l2"); 
vp.add(new Label("l3"); 

vp.addDomHandler(new DragOverHandler() {
  public void onDragOver(DragOverEvent event) {
    vp.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("#ffa");
  }
}, com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DragOverEvent.getType());

vp.addDomHandler(new DropHandler() {            
  @Override
  public void onDrop(com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DropEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get the data out of the event.
    String data = event.getData("text");
    //Window.alert(data);
    /// WE NEED TO FILL IN THE MISSING CODE HERE
    /// WE NEED TO FILL IN THE MISSING CODE HERE
  }
}, DropEvent.getType());
```

how to code so that when user drag the outside label into the area of `VerticalPanel`, if the outside label was dragged between the existing widgets, it will be inserted into the between of existing labels on `VerticalPanel`, Ex if the outside label was drag between "l1" & "l2", the `vp` will show:

l1

OutSide Label

l2

l3

Comment: You need to use VerticalPanel api insert(IsWidget w, int beforeIndex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should theoretically work, although not tested:

```
p.addDomHandler(new DropHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
    // Get the target event.
    EventTarget eventTarget = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget();
    // Safe check for casting to Element.
    if (Element.is(eventTarget)) {
      Element elementTarget = Element.as(eventTarget);
      // Loop through VerticalPanel's children to find our target.
      for (int i = 0; i < p.getWidgetCount(); ++i) {
        if (p.getWidget(i).getElement().isOrHasChild(elementTarget)) {
          // Insert a new Label with the DataTransfer's data,
          // and remove the old one.
          p.insert(new Label(event.getData("text")), i);
          oldLabelContainer.remove(oldLabel);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, DropEvent.getType());
```

Of course, if you have *a lot of labels* that loop should be avoided.

Comment: it's Perfect!

Andrea Boscolo! Thank you very much!**** 5 Stars!!

Comment: Guys this solutions work well in Chrome but in firefox it works well but immediately it fires some internal event which changes the url in browser and trys to launch it. Is there any solution for this?